# Take a huge screenshot of a webpage (over 13500x13500px size)

Tags: javascript, php, web, screenshot

I have about 3000 images of about 256x256px size (but some are 50x256 and some are 256x100 or so) which I wish to merge into one big picture. The images are shown in a webpage, thus the easiest way would be to take a screenshot of the said webpage. The webpage's image is of about **13500x13500px** ! On theory, I could download all of the images and merge them together (with like bitmap() or CopyImage() or something like that but I really wish to go with an easier solution). Oh and this 3000->1 is one of about 120 in total cases that I have to do.

I've tried several methods, none of which worked out properly:

- phantomJS (the .exe crashes after a while)
- CutyCaps (the .exe crashes after a while)
- Firefox's "screenshot --fullpage bla.png" (crashes with exception,
  known issue with huge pages since the dawn of firefox)
- SeleniumSDK (FirefoxDriver, crashes after a while)
- html2canvas (crashes or just won't start)
- basic javascript and canvas work (failed miserably)
- A dozen of the top extensions for firefox (takes forever, then
  crashes or produces a broken image)
- A dozen of the top extensions for Chrome (takes forever, then
  crashes or produces a broken image)

The **only** service that ever worked out perfectly was http://web-capture.net but I really wish to have an offline/local method to generate the image, due to the amount of times that I'd have to visit any 3th party website.

If anyone could point me to any better offline service or a solution, I would be very grateful. Any working code snippets (preferably in either php/javascript/java/selenium/c#) are highly appreciated.

*More on the project itself:*

The source data is a photograph of a cell, shown with LeafletJS (similar to GoogleMaps). I made up a web scraper of sort, which pulls all the data from the viewer page and shows them as a one huge picture, formed out of thousands of other smaller images (with sometimes different sizes). The Histology course has about 120 different images that I'd wish to have locally stored, hence this whole exercise. Also, to make stuff interesting, every image is of different size, but lets say that it has about 55-60 columns and 50-80 rows of small 256x256 images, forming the big picture.

Here is a preview of what I'm talking about:

http://89.215.196.209/Anatomy%20%28Histology%29%20data%20parser.htm

*Sorry for the long post, have a cookie.*

Comment: Assembling the images directly using a tool like [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/), something usually loaded into PHP by default, is way better than this approach.

Comment: I do not wish to download 120 times 3000-3500 images and then to merge them with a 3td party software. Have you actually read my post?

Comment: @BlooDev, have the thought of running the app on the server crossed your mind? No need to download anything, and you can use a proper tool for the job...

Comment: Which app on which server? I do not have access to the original server. I'm gathering all of the images on my own, if i CTRL+S I can then save all images. My goal is entirely different-> I wish to take a screenshot of a web page which has just finished loading completely. Is it really that hard to comprehend?

Comment: No need to be so aggressive, @tadman is trying to help you. I concur that ImageMagick would be an excellent tool for this. It has a montage option that does exactly what you want to do: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/montage/  Many servers have ImageMagick installed, is there no way you could go this route?

Comment: ImageMagick can of course be installed locally too. But then you would need to download all the images. A tool like 'wget' or any automated download plugin for your browser could do this automatically though.

Comment: Sure, if you give me one valid reason as to why should I use ImageMagic in which I have to manually organize the images when I can just take a screenshot (like the topic says) of a webpage. I apologize if I sound aggressive, I am not.

Comment: Didn't you say that taking a screenshot crashed every application/method you tried? That might be a good reason to try something else...

Comment: Yes, all but one failed, only http://web-capture.net didn't failed.

I just wanted a faster/local solution, since now I have to wait about 15secs for the image to be generated via that service.

Comment: @BlooDev You do sound awfully combative. Using HTML to composite images is a really unusual way to go about doing this. I also don't think downloading a bunch of images is tricky or hard, `wget` can do it in a heartbeat with the right options. Using ImageMagick gives you complete control over how they're arranged, and most importantly, what sort of output you're getting and what size it is.

Comment: That link just crashed my phone and i reboot it lol

Comment: Again, I apologize. Yes, I do know that doing image processing like that is strange and the reason why I didn't wan to go with wget and such is the extra hassle. I already had a simple and easy and relatively fast solution, my main question was if it's doable even faster and if there is any actual way of doing a massive screenshot with javascript.
Let's say that tomorrow i have actually a webpage with 15k x15k size, what then?
@HddnTHA Now you feel my pain :D Once, while debuging my firefox froze for about 15minutes trying to load it xD

Comment: Good luck with huge images (-:

Answer (score 0):

I actually just installed and checked out the 64x ver of wkhtmltoimage and it works out perfectly.